# $mdToast, $mdDialog is not working in route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing, material-design

I was happily calling `$mdDialog.show` or `$mdToast.show`but I started to use `$routeProvider`, I can't use them anymore, I'm getting this error **when I tried to open toast or dialog**:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'overflow' of undefined
at forEach.css (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.js:2831:27)
at Object.JQLite.(anonymous function) [as css] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.js:2944:27)
at Object.s [as onShow] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.7.0/angular-material.min.js:121:1344)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.7.0/angular-material.min.js:55:2782
at processQueue (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.js:13137:27)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.js:13153:27
at Scope.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.js:14353:28)
at Scope.$digest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.js:14169:31)
at Scope.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.js:14457:24)
at done (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.js:9614:47)
```

Here is my app:

```
var app = angular.module('APP', ['ngMaterial', 'ngRoute'])

app.config(['$routeProvider',
function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/assets/tpl/ana.tmp.html',
            controller: 'cbiKontrol'
        })
}]);
app.controller('cbiKontrol', ['$scope', '$mdDialog', '$window', '$mdToast', '$location' , function($scope, $mdDialog, $window, $mdToast, $location){

   var toastShow = function(content) {
       $mdToast.show({
         template: '<md-toast><span flex>'+content+'</span></md-toast>',
         hideDelay: 1800,
         position: "top right"
       })
   }
   //toastShow("test") 
})
```

`ana.tmp.html` only has a lot of divs.

index.tmp.html (when the page is first rendered):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/stil.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.7.0/angular-material.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=RobotoDraft:400,500,700,400italic">
<script src="http://hammerjs.github.io/dist/hammer.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.7.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="APP" ng-view></body>
</html>
```

What can be the problem? I want to use Dialog and Toast classes. I'm new to angularjs.

Comment: you haven't shown any code which has the Angular-Material Directives that you are asking about.

Comment: @Claies Thanks for remind. I'm using : https://material.angularjs.org/#/demo/material.components.dialog https://material.angularjs.org/#/demo/material.components.toast

Comment: right, those are the Directives, but you aren't showing here where you are calling them in your code.

Comment: so that function is just a global variable sitting in your app.js file?

Comment: does the error go away if you load `angular-material.min.js` before `angular-route.min.js` instead of after?

Comment: @Claies Thanks for suggestion, but it stayed same.

Comment: your code looks correct, I can't see anything that would create this conflict.  you might want to file a bug report for the material design team.  https://github.com/angular/material/issues/new

Comment: I'm submitting it now.

Comment: Can you link to the bug report? I'm getting the same issue now, but I'm not sure if it's related to $routeProvider since I've always been using it and didn't have issues initially.

Comment: @eshortie, https://github.com/angular/material/issues/1542 solution inside.

Comment: @Lazy thanks! What a strange solution. Moving ng-view from body to another tag.